# Image Prediction fails on Chrome Mobile using tfjs but works on Chrome Desktop

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, mobile-chrome

There is a simple classification *keras* model that i have converted to *tfjs* model, it works completely fine on Desktop Chrome predicts images as it should but on Chrome Mobile I receive the following error on calling the **predict** function:

```
Uncaught Error: Requested texture size [5120x5120] greater than WebGL maximum on this browser / GPU [4096x4096].
at validateTextureSize (tfjs@0.12.0:2)
at createAndConfigureTexture (tfjs@0.12.0:2)
at createFloat32MatrixTexture (tfjs@0.12.0:2)
at e.createFloat32MatrixTexture (tfjs@0.12.0:2)
at e.acquireTexture (tfjs@0.12.0:2)
at e.acquireTexture (tfjs@0.12.0:2)
at e.uploadToGPU (tfjs@0.12.0:2)
at tfjs@0.12.0:2
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at e.compileAndRun (tfjs@0.12.0:2)
```

As I understand Chrome Mobile has some limitations on texture size and my model exceeds those thus the error.

My question is how would i go about solving this issue?

Should i retrain my model and make it smaller in size so as to work on Mobile or is there some other solution?

Note: The current model in tfjs format is around 112MB.

Comment: Do you have something in your model, which uses tensors of size 5120? If yes, I think it would be the easiest option to reduce it, if you don't lose to much accuracy. But if your model is this big, is it really a good idea to run it on a mobile device in terms of performance?

Comment: The error output indicates that the size of the input of your model is too big. It excedes the size the mobile browser can handle [4096x4096]. So consider retraining your model using smaller batch size

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I just wanted to add my discoveries on the matter as I ran into the same problem recently.

What is happening is: the image is converted into a tensors with tf.image.fromPixels. The image, then, get cropped and resized. Finally, to operate with WebGL, the tensor is being stored inside textures. Here's where it fails.

Max texture size is dependent on device and browser. Almost all modern devices can handle up to 2048 x 2048 textures. We can't do [anything](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/689#issuecomment-503590183) about it.

The size of the tensor DOES NOT depend on:

- Resolution of the input
- Size of the input
- Number of output nodes in the converted model
- Type of output nodes in the converted model
- Quantization Bytes used to convert the model
- Trainig dataset

The only thing that worked for me was to change the starting pre-trained model. So I switched from `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco` to `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. Models would work fine on desktop but would crash when trying to use model.predict on mobile. For my issue, I was able to track this down to being due to the size of my convolutional kernels. I found that I am able to use convolutional kernels up to size (6,6) without running into problems on mobile. If I go up to (7,7) or greater, I get the texture size error. This problem didn't have anything to do with the input size for me.